# Is it possible to fetch Approval process meta data using VS Code?

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, approval-process, vs-code

I am trying to fetch approval process metadata from one of my development org and deploy it to another development org, but I could not find a way to fetch the metadata regarding the approval process. I have checked this document by could not fetch it
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_approvalprocess.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should be possible by putting this to package.xml

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>ApprovalProcess</name>
</types>
```

If you want to retrieve it individually the change the `members` node to include your required approval processes:

```
<members>Account.Approve_New_Account</members>
```